# iPhone 5 Layout for a bar hiding within a view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I wonder if anyone could kindly assist, I am trying to adjust my app so that it recognises the full screen of the iPhone 5, it all works fine on other screens now, however my initial screen I am having an issue with, as I fade the top and bottom bars out of view, the top works fine however the bottom does not, could anyone assist with the code to help me get it to work on the iPhone 5? As right now, the bar is too high on the screen on iPhone 5 and does not fade out of view...

```
- (void)barwillGo
{

     if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{

                         CGRect top = CGRectMake(0, -51, 320, 50);

                         if (CGRectEqualToRect(topBar.frame,top))
                         {

                             [topBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
                             [bottomBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 50)];

                             }

                         else {
                             [topBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -51, 320, 50)];
                             [bottomBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 481, 320, 50)];
                         }


                     }
                     completion:nil];
     }
     else {
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                               delay:0.0f
                             options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                          animations:^{

                              CGRect top = CGRectMake(0, -51, 768, 50);

                              if (CGRectEqualToRect(topBar.frame,top))
                              {

                                  [topBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 50)];
                                  [bottomBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 974, 768, 50)];

                              }

                              else {
                                  [topBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -51, 768, 50)];
                                  [bottomBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 1025, 768, 50)];
                              }


                          }
                          completion:nil];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hard coded the CGRect values of the bottomBar to the 3.5 inch screen dimensions.

Try something like this within your first animation block:

```
CGRect bounds = topView.superview.bounds;
CGFloat topRectY, bottomRectY;
if(topBar.frame.origin.y == -50){
   topRectY = 0;
   bottomRectY = bounds.size.height - 50;
} else {
   topRectY = -50;
   bottomRectY = bounds.size.height;
}
topBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, topRectY, bounds.size.width, 50);
bottomBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, bottomRectY, bounds.size.width, 50);
```

Comment: Superb, thank you that is an excellent solution - really appreciate you helping me, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{

                             CGRect top = CGRectMake(0, -51, 320, 50);

                             if (CGRectEqualToRect(topBar.frame,top))
                             {

                                 [topBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
                                 [bottomBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 50)];

                             }

                             else {
//check device iphone5 or not
                                 if (screenHeight != 568.0f) {
                                     [topBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -51, 320, 50)];
                                     [bottomBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 481, 320, 50)];
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     [topBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -51, 320, 50)];
                                     [bottomBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 569, 320, 50)];
                                 }
                             }


                         }
                         completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: Hi NANNAV - this solution works also however the starting place for the bar was further up on the iPhone 5, Nick C solution worked but I would like to thank you also for your help.